# IELTS Reading True/False/Not given question

Tags: exam-questions, ielts, reading-comprehension

I'm studying for my IELTS test but I'm having a hard time with some T/F/NG questions. For example, in the text "New York Late-starters String Orchestra" we have the question:

5. Rehearsals always involve the full orchestra playing together. (Key answer: FALSE)

The passage says:

> "Our professional tutor/facilitator serves as coach and conductor during rehearsals. Substitute conductors also join in to teach different sections, providing groups of players with valuable experience in working with different approaches and styles. Everyone is encouraged to play to their fullest potential, whatever that may be, but please recognize that while we do have a conductor, her role is not to provide one-on-one instruction during rehearsals".

But I just cannot see what makes this sentence FALSE. I understood that "sections" means differents parts of a song. Is this the problem?

Comment: "sections" means "sections of the orchestra" and "groups of players" implies the full orchestra isn't playing

Comment: But the text is about a *string orchestra*, which doesn't have 'sections', only 'parts' (vn 1, vn 2 etc). @Roser: Is that all of the text? Does it mention woodwind, brass or percussion?

Answer (score 2):

Where does the extract say that rehearsals ALWAYS include the FULL orchestra? Nowhere.

That is what many candidates may automatically assume about rehearsals but it doesn't actually say so in the passage. It says that rehearsals involve **sections** of the orchestra, for example musicians that play a certain type of instrument such as brass, woodwind, percussion.

> [The Sections of the Orchestra](https://courses.lumenlearning.com/musicappreciation_with_theory/chapter/orchestral-instruments/#:%7E:text=found%20in%20them.-,The%20Sections%20of%20the%20Orchestra,woodwinds%2C%20brass%2C%20and%20percussion.)
> The typical orchestra is divided into four groups of instruments: strings, woodwinds, brass, and percussion.

[Symphony Orchestras](https://courses.lumenlearning.com/musicappreciation_with_theory/chapter/symphony-orchestras/)

> An orchestra is a large instrumental ensemble that contains **sections of string** (violin, viola, cello, and double bass), **brass, woodwind, and percussion instruments**. Other instruments such as the piano and celesta may sometimes be grouped into a fifth section such as **a keyboard sectio**n or may stand alone, as may the concert harp and electric and electronic instruments.